# WTForms only submits first form

Tags: javascript, python, forms, wtforms

I have a blog page where users can add their replies and that works just fine.

I also have an edit feature, but it isn't working. Just the first one does.

When for example, I submit the second or third form the first one gets always submitted. But when I submit the first one the second one is submitted.

The following is Jinja2 WTForms code

```
{% for item in items %}    
<form method=post action="/reply/edit">      
  {{reply-form.content}}
  <input type=submit value="Submit">    
{% endfor %}
```

and the following is the function getting executed when a certain route is called (/reply/edit)

```
def reply_edit():
    reply-form = Reply(request.forms)
    if reply-form.validate():
        content = reply-form.data['content']
        return content
    else:
        return 'houston, we have a problem'
```

Basically forms are laid out like this when unexpanded

```
---------------------
|    first form     |
|                   |
---------------------
----------   --------
| delete |   | edit |
----------   --------

---------------------
|    second form    |
|                   |
---------------------
----------   --------
| delete |   | edit |
----------   --------

---------------------
|    third form     |
|                   |
---------------------
----------   --------
| delete |   | edit |
----------   --------

.........
```

and like this when expanded

```
---------------------
|    first form     |
|                   |
---------------------
----------   ----------
| submit |   | cancel |
----------   ----------

---------------------
|    second form    |
|                   |
---------------------
----------   ----------
| submit |   | cancel |
----------   ----------

---------------------
|    third form     |
|                   |
---------------------
----------   ----------
| submit |   | cancel |
----------   ----------

.........
```

I'm trying since yesterday without success and ultimately pulling my hair.

What can be the problem here?

Comment: The closing element for form is missing from the code snippet. Missing in the real app as well?

Comment: @eclaird Yes! how did I miss that?! I solved the problem, but it was really dumb for me to forget that tag. Wish there was a syntax checker to check for missing HTML tags, it would make life easier! Thank you for pointing that out :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, the closing tag for `form` seems to be missing.